# Dynamic loading of react components inside state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have a really interesting problem at hand.

I am currently working on a Admin-Interface for a headless CMS and I want to dynamically load the components for viewing the content of different parts.

I know that it is rather easy to accomplish wit React Router since v4, but I don't want to rely on Routes to handle this to keep the URL as clean as possible.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. I want to render the basic layout of the UI (in which I load the
   different sub-components when clicking the navigation-links)
2. Inside the `async componentWillMount()` function of this basic layout I want to `import()` said components using `await import()`
3. Ideally those should be stored to the state inside a property called `this.state.mainComponents`
4. I will then pass down the names of the components to the navigation component along with a function which will change the currently displayed component in the parents `state`

I tried several different approaches, but did not manage to get it to work until now.

This is what I have now:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const mainComponents = {
      Dashboard: await import('../_mainComponents/Dashboard').then(
        ({ Dashboard }) => {
          return Dashboard;
        },
      ),
    };

    const componentNames = [];

    for (let p in mainComponents) {
      componentNames.push(p);
    }

    this.setState({
      mainComponents: {
        views: mainComponents,
        names: componentNames,
      },
      currentComponent: mainComponents.Dashboard,
      currentTitle: 'Dashboard',
    });
  }
```

I would really appreciate any help you could give me on this.

EDIT:

So according to the answer of @Mosè Raguzzini I implemented `react-loadable` again and tried to store the const inside my state like this:

```
const LoadableDashboard = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../_mainComponents/Dashboard'),
  loading: Loading
});

const mainComponents = {
  Dashboard: LoadableDashboard
};
```

And inside my constructor function I am trying to pass this Object into the state like this:

```
const componentNames = [];

for (let p in mainComponents) {
  componentNames.push(p);
}

this.state = {
  mainComponents: {
    views: mainComponents,
    names: componentNames,
  },
  currentComponent: null,
  currentTitle: null,
  loading: false,
};
```

It is not working when trying to output the Components stored inside the `this.state.mainComponents.views` object inside to the render function.

When using `<Dashboard />` it is working as expected, but this is not what I am trying to accomplish here since I don't want to add every component to the render function in a massive `switch ... case`.

Does anybody of you have an idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem and wanted to share it with all of those who will come after me searching for an appropiate answer.

Here is what I did:

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import Loading from '../_helperComponents/Loading';

// Define the async-loadable components here and store them inside of the mainComponent object
const LoadableDashboard = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../_mainComponents/Dashboard'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const LoadableUserOverview = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../_mainComponents/UserOverview'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const mainComponents = {
  Dashboard: <LoadableDashboard />,
  User: <LoadableUserOverview />,
};
```

I do not store the components inside my state (it would have been possible but goes against the guidelines as I've found out by researching state even further) :D

With this object I can simply call the corresponding component by outputting it in the `render()` function like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {mainComponents[this.state.currentComponent]}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope I could help someone with this. 
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look to react-loadable:

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import Loading from './my-loading-component';

const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./my-component'),
  loading: Loading,
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoadableComponent/>;
  }
}
```

It provides the feature you need in a clean style.

Comment: Well, I did just that and the one thing I am missing there is the possibility to store those Components inside my state. It could also be possible that sth went wrong during my implementation, but I will give it another try. So thanks for your input.

Comment: In  developer's intentions (it isn't a constrain) state must be serializable, so it is better to store in it only plain objects.
Furthermore loadable has really nice features like preload, or triggers for preloading (IE: Start preloading components while you are hovering a button)

Comment: I already digged through the loadable docs and found it indeed very useful. I will give it a try with some of the more specific components, when it comes to fine-tune my application. Thanks for that tip.